# How to reference Liquibase changelogs that are located alongside the executing SpringBoot jar rather than packaged inside the jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, jar, classpath, liquibase

I have a Spring Boot 2.7.7 project which will be responsible for performing Liquibase database migrations.

The application will be packaged as a `.jar`, and then later the `.jar` and a collection of Liquibase changelogs will be packaged into a Docker image.

Since the changelogs are not packaged inside the `.jar`, they are located in the same directory as the `.jar` at runtime on the Docker container.

This is the basic structure of the application:

```
data-migration:
  src/
    main/
      java/
        com.example.demo/
          SpringBootApplication.java
          LiquibaseUpdate.java
      resources/
        application.properties
  build.gradle.kts
```

In `SpringBootApplication.java`:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Trying to add additional directory containing the changelogs to classpath
    System.setProperty(
        "java.class.path",
        System.getProperty("java.class.path")
            + ":/Users/rbyrne/git/data-migration/build/libs:.");

    new SpringApplicationBuilder(SpringBootApplication.class)
        .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
        .run(args);
  }
}
```

`LiquibaseUpdate.java`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({LiquibaseProperties.class})
public class LiquibaseUpdate {

  @Bean
  public SpringLiquibase liquibase(
      @Qualifier("taskExecutor") TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
      DataSource dataSource,
      LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties)
      throws Exception {
    SpringLiquibase liquibase = new SpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setShouldRun(false); // do not run against public schema
    return liquibase;
  }

  @Bean("liquibaseMultiTenant")
  @DependsOn("liquibase") // ensure execution after SpringLiquibase Bean
  public MultiTenantSpringLiquibase liquibaseMultiTenant(
      DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {
    MultiTenantSpringLiquibase liquibase = new MultiTenantSpringLiquibase();
    liquibase.setShouldRun(true);
    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
    liquibase.setContexts(liquibaseProperties.getContexts());
    liquibase.setLabels(liquibaseProperties.getLabels());
    liquibase.setChangeLog("config/liquibase/changelog/root-changelog.xml");
    liquibase.setSchemas(Arrays.asList("tenant1", "tenant2"));
    return liquibase;
  }
}
```

This is the error:

```
2023-03-23 15:06:13.596  WARN 96151 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'liquibaseMultiTenant' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/liquibase/LiquibaseCUpdate.class]: 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.ChangeLogParseException: 
The file config/liquibase/changelog/root-changelog.xml was not found in the configured search path:
    - Spring classpath
More locations can be added with the 'searchPath' parameter.
```

This is the state of the filesystem:

```
work build/libs ‹main*› » pwd
/Users/rbyrne/git/data-migration/build/libs
work build/libs ‹main*› » ls
data-migration-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-plain.jar   data-migration-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
data-migration-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT-sources.jar config
work build/libs ‹main*› » ls config/liquibase/changelog/
root-changelog.xml
```

I've tried setting the Liquibase `searchPath` property inside `application.properties` with different variations but none have any effect:

```
liquibase.search-path=./
liquibase.searchPath=./
```

Comment: which version of liquibase it is?

Comment: @bilak Liquibase `4.20.0`

Comment: if you specify absolute path (e.g. `/Users/rbyrne/git/data-migration/build/libs/config/liquibase/changelog/root-changelog.xml`) does it work?